# Struts 1.2 decrease float precision in <bean:write> tag

Tags: java, struts, precision

I have the following code in my jsp :

```
<bean:write name="contract" property="percentage"/>
```

the property percentage returns a float.

My problem is that I need to decrease the float's precision (only for display) to 3 decimals like a System.out.printf("%.3f", value);

How can I do that within my bean:write tag ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I just discovered the format attribute :

```
<bean:write name="contract" property="percentage" format="###.###"/>
```

Sorry for the inconveniance.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you a little and so simple workaround. Create a getter method like **percentagePrecission** to return the float's precision you want.

In example:

```
public class YourClass{

public float percentage;

//getters, setters and other properties

public String percentagePrecision(){
   return percentage's precision
}


}
```